# Updating field from 3 different tables

Tags: sql

I have a question using below 3 tables:

```
1. Company (table)
CONAME
COPOINTS

2. Group_Member (table)
CONAME
NAME

3. Member (table)
NAME
MPOINTS
```

I would like to have a correct query with the following condition:

```
Update Member
Set MPOINTS=MPOINTS+5
Where Company.CONAME=Group_Member.CONAME
And
Group_Member.NAME=Member.NAME
```

Can you please correct above query?

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL (MS-SQL Server dialect) this would be

```
Update Member
   set MPOINTS = MPOINTS + 5
  from Group_Member 
       join Company on Company.CONAME = Group_Member.CONAME
 where Group_Member.NAME = Member.NAME
```

I would like to remind you, that names are not a good choice for neither primary nor foreign key relations. You will never be able to change a name without violating primary key constraints. Use a (numeric, autoincrement) ID column instead.

Comment: Please post the contents of your tables. If the contents does not match, how do you think it can work? The statement provided does work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Update M
Set    MPOINTS=MPOINTS+5
from   Member M 
join   Group_Member GM
on     GM.NAME=M.NAME
join   Company C
on     C.CONAME=GM.CONAME
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005+

```
UPDATE x
SET x.MPOINTS += 5
FROM (SELECT m.MPOINTS FROM Company c JOIN Group_Member g ON c.CONAME = g.CONAME
                                      JOIN Member m ON g.NAME = m.NAME) x
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

Comment: If replace SET x.MPOINTS += 5 on SET x.MPOINTS = x.MPOINTS + 5 what will be result?

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Member.m'.

Comment: I used this SET x.MPOINTS = x.MPOINTS + 5 and
JOIN Member m ON g.NAME = m.NAME) x
Result is:
(0 row(s) affected)